# Mybatis batch insert performance slow down on JDK upgrade

Tags: java, java-8, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

We are upgrading our jdk from 1.8.0_51 to 1.8.0_251.
Project is using spring, spring-mybatis with oracle db.
There are some mapper.insert calls in the code where the performance deteriorates too much.
Data inserted - 100000 to a table of 14 columns.
Time deteriorates by 100x. For new code takes more than 8000 seconds.
Mybatis insert code details-
Mybatis session: ExecutorType.BATCH, autocommit=false
Inserting 20000 rows at a time.

Investigated the mybatis debug logs. It prints only the SQL, which does not have any difference.

Cannot add code here due to org restriction.

Comment: Is JDK version the only difference? Have you verified that reverting JDK version to 1.8.0_51 resolves the performance issue?

Comment: Yes, after the issue occured with JDK 1.8.0_251, I ran the code with JDK 1.8.0_51 and it ran as usual. There is no change in the codebase for the runs.

Comment: I have run the latest runs with mybatis mapper logging option switched on to TRACE. It prints DEBUG logs for the SQL with parameters. For JDK 1.8.0_51 there were 5/6 insert queries created per 1ms. But for JDK 1.8.0_251 it was creating 1 query per 10ms and the time seems to be increasing (still running).

Comment: Interesting. I understand that you cannot post the actual code, but is it possible to provide a small app like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) that replicates the performance difference between 1.8.0_51 and 1.8.0_251 using dummy table/class names? I may be able to get to the bottom if I could reproduce the issue on my end. If that is also difficult, finding out the exact [JDK update](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html) that makes the difference might give us a hint.

Comment: I asked my lead, addition of code can get me to serious issues. The old JDK is Java SE Development Kit 8u51 - [8u51](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u51-relnotes.html). The new JDK - [8u251](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u251-relnotes.html). I cannot find the new JDK in the link you shared.

Comment: Can you help me out with what kind of further investigation would be a good idea to go ahead from here, with the code base available.

Comment: JDK 8u211 and later can be found [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html). I wrote a [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/so-62538376/so-62538376) based on the info you provided and it runs in about 6-9 seconds on 8u251. You should 1) verify my demo runs fast on your environment and 2) compare it with your app and figure out what the key difference is.